# Does MPI_Finalize have to be called inside the main function?

Tags: mpi

Just curious if I could call it within another function call.

Comment: What is your question? Why did you just repeat the same thing multiple times.

Comment: Question is in title.

Answer (score 4):

No. You can call MPI_Finalize inside of any function. The only restrictions pertain to calling from threads. See the [MPI standard](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.1/mpi31-report/node302.htm#Node302) for details.